# Extracting data from XMLDocument

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <GetMessage xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <GetMessageResult>
                <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
                    <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
                        <xs:complexType>
                            <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                <xs:element name="inLogSMS">
                                    <xs:complexType>
                                        <xs:sequence>
                                            <xs:element name="InLogID" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="FromMobile" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="ContactName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="SMSText" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="ReceiveAt" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="Status" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                        </xs:sequence>
                                    </xs:complexType>
                                </xs:element>
                            </xs:choice>
                        </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                </xs:schema>
                <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
                    <NewDataSet xmlns="">
                        <inLogSMS diffgr:id="SMS1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
                            <InLogID></InLogID>
                            <FromMobile></FromMobile>
                            <ContactName></ContactName>
                            <SMSText>Test2</SMSText>
                            <ReceiveAt></ReceiveAt>
                            <Status>New</Status>
                        </inLogSMS>
                        <inLogSMS diffgr:id="SMS2" msdata:rowOrder="1">
                            <InLogID></InLogID>
                            <FromMobile></FromMobile>
                            <ContactName></ContactName>
                            <SMSText>TEST</SMSText>
                            <ReceiveAt></ReceiveAt>
                            <Status>New</Status>
                        </inLogSMS>
                    </NewDataSet>
                </diffgr:diffgram>
            </GetMessageResult>
        </GetMessage>
```

I been trying for days, anyone can tell me how to extract the data for SMSText element and Status Element. Thank you very much. There is too much tag till i am confuse

var responseXml = new XmlDocument();

XmlNodeList items = responseXml.GetElementsByTagName("/GetMessage/inLogSMS");
            foreach (XmlNode xItem in items)
            {
                string id = xItem["SMSText"].InnerText;
                Console.WriteLine(id);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even need the XPath-like expression to access the elements:

```
XmlDocument responseXml = new XmlDocument();
responseXml.Load("path to your XML");

foreach (XmlElement e in responseXml.GetElementsByTagName("inLogSMS"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Text: " + e.GetElementsByTagName("SMSText")[0].InnerText);
    Console.WriteLine("Status: " + e.GetElementsByTagName("Status")[0].InnerText);
}
```

Instead of `XmlDocument` you could use `XDocument`.

At first, you need to load the XML; there are two ways of doing so: 
1. `XDocument x = XDocument.Parse("your XML as string");` 
2. `XDocument x = XDocument.Load("The path to your XML");`

After that, you can access any element by using `Descendants()`.

For example:

```
foreach (var e in x.Descendants("inLogSMS"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Text: " + e.Element("SMSText").Value);
    Console.WriteLine("Status: " + e.Element("Status").Value);
}
```

Both ways will print:

> Text: Test2
>  Status: New
>  Text: TEST
>  Status: New

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing with a SOAP message. You don't reveal how you got that content but I expect you didn't get it from a [WCF Client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/building-clients) as that would have solved most of your problems.

Luckily the [System.ServiceModel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel?view=netframework-4.7.2) namespace has plenty of support classes to deal with SOAP messages.

That XML you show is a SOAP Envelope and Body with a wrapped return of a DataSet. While you can go fiddle with XmlDocument or XDocument you can obtain that data from within the standard classes offered.

Let's look at how the [Message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.channels.message?view=netframework-4.7.2) class can help us here.

It offers methods to read the [body](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.channels.message.getbody?view=netframework-4.7.2) of SOAP serialized messages.

```
// using System.Runtime.Serialization
// using System.ServiceModel.Channels

GetMessage body; // GetMessage is our custon serialization class
using(var rdr = XmlReader.Create(@"your.xml"))  // or use StringReader / MemoryStream
{
  var msg = Message.CreateMessage(rdr, Int32.MaxValue, MessageVersion.Soap11);
  body = msg.GetBody<GetMessage>();
}
// Now we can simply iterate over the Table
foreach(DataRow smsrow in body.GetMessageResult.Tables["inlogSMS"].Rows)
{
  // and smsrow has the fields in its ItemArray (accessible by its indexer)
  Console.WriteLine("Text: {0} with status {1}", smsrow["SMSText"], smsrow["Status"]);
}
```

The above code will output:

> ```
> Text: Test2 with status New
> Text: TEST with status New
> ```

The serialization class you need will look like this:

```
[DataContract(Name="GetMessage", Namespace="http://tempuri.org/")]
public class GetMessage
{
  [DataMember]
  public DataSet GetMessageResult {get;set;} // this will hold the DataSet
}
```